# applescript screen-shot automator buggy when exported as .app

Tags: applescript, screenshot, handler

so, I am making an app that takes screenshots at a regular interval for a customizable amount of time. I'm having a hard time with it because when I run the app in the applescript editor, everything is fine - but when I export it to an .app, things are buggy, and if the user clicks on the app icon, it will trigger the "repeat" code, and if the user tries to quit, it behaves erratically.

I read in other posts that on idle could work, but I don't know how to end an idle handler after a specified amount of time.

Anybody knows the solution to my conundrum? Thank you!

```
on run

set frequencyList to {2, 5, 10, 15}

set durationList to {30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180}

choose from list durationList with prompt "how long (in minutes) would you like to snap screenshots for?"
set chosenDuration to result as number
set chosenDurationSeconds to chosenDuration * 60


choose from list frequencyList with prompt "how often (in minutes) would you like to snap a screenshot?"
set chosenFrequency to result as number
set chosenFrequencySeconds to chosenFrequency * 60

set repeatNumber to chosenDurationSeconds / chosenFrequencySeconds

display dialog "Great! I'll take " & repeatNumber & " photos over the span of " & chosenDuration & " minutes."
display dialog "Next, choose where you want these to end up."

set FolderPath to POSIX path of (choose folder) as string

display dialog "Sounds good! Just let me run in the background, and I'll snap away until the time is up."

delay 1

repeat repeatNumber times
    set theCurrentDate to current date
    set shellCommand to "/usr/sbin/screencapture \"" & FolderPath & "Screen Shot" & theCurrentDate & ".png\""
    do shell script shellCommand
    delay chosenFrequencySeconds
end repeat
```

end run

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you would write your code with an "on idle" handler (I didn't test it). Remember to save this as a "stay open application". Notice that you tell the on idle handler to repeat in seconds in the last line of the handler. Notice also that we quit the app at the calculated date rather than repeating a number of times. You could essentially make a counter to count the loops of the idle handler but the date method is easier. Finally notice we have global variables. This makes the variables initiated in the on run handler available to the on idle handler.

Good luck.

```
global quitTime, chosenFrequencySeconds, FolderPath

on run
    set frequencyList to {2, 5, 10, 15}
    set durationList to {30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180}

    choose from list durationList with prompt "how long (in minutes) would you like to snap screenshots for?"
    set chosenDuration to result as number
    set quitTime to (current date) + chosenDuration * minutes

    choose from list frequencyList with prompt "how often (in minutes) would you like to snap a screenshot?"
    set chosenFrequency to result as number
    set chosenFrequencySeconds to chosenFrequency * 60

    display dialog "Great! I'll take " & repeatNumber & " photos over the span of " & chosenDuration & " minutes."
    display dialog "Next, choose where you want these to end up."

    set FolderPath to POSIX path of (choose folder) as string

    display dialog "Sounds good! Just let me run in the background, and I'll snap away until the time is up."

    delay 1
end run

on idle
    set theCurrentDate to current date
    set shellCommand to "/usr/sbin/screencapture " & quoted form of (FolderPath & "Screen Shot" & (theCurrentDate as text) & ".png")
    do shell script shellCommand

    if theCurrentDate is greater than or equal to quitTime then tell me to quit
    return chosenFrequencySeconds
end idle
```

Comment: thanks so much! it's the tell me to quit part that I was missing :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to implement a `reopen` handler. I have done so with regulus's code, and it worked for me, if the applet is installed in the dock, then it starts the first, time, if it is clicked later on, you'll get a message that it is already running. The `reopen` handler probably have some superfluos code, like testing for if the app is running, and activating it, since the reopen handler should only be triggered when the app is already running. But I'll leave that for you, at least it doesn't execute the run handler now. :)

```
  global quitTime, chosenFrequencySeconds, FolderPath

  on run
    set frequencyList to {2, 5, 10, 15}
    set durationList to {30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180}

    choose from list durationList with prompt "how long (in minutes) would you like to snap screenshots for?"
    set chosenDuration to result as number
    set quitTime to (current date) + chosenDuration * minutes

    choose from list frequencyList with prompt "how often (in minutes) would you like to snap a screenshot?"
    set chosenFrequency to result as number
    set chosenFrequencySeconds to chosenFrequency * 60

    display dialog "Great! I'll take " & chosenFrequency & " photos over the span of " & chosenDuration & " minutes."
    display dialog "Next, choose where you want these to end up."

    set FolderPath to POSIX path of (choose folder) as string

    display dialog "Sounds good! Just let me run in the background, and I'll snap away until the time is up."

    delay 1
  end run

  on idle
    set theCurrentDate to current date
    set shellCommand to "/usr/sbin/screencapture " & quoted form of (FolderPath & "Screen Shot" & (theCurrentDate as text) & ".png")
    do shell script shellCommand

    if theCurrentDate is greater than or equal to quitTime then tell me to quit
    return chosenFrequencySeconds
  end idle

  on reopen
    if running of me then
        tell me
            activate
            display alert "Already running"
        end tell
    end if
  end reopen
```

Comment: This is really interesting! Thanks so much.